# Local Java Data Structure Causing OOM Error in Spark Map Call

Tags: apache-spark

I'm trying to run a `mapToPair` function on a `javaPairRDD` of about 1.5 million entries. Outside of the call, I have a Java `Map` that's locally defined. If I access the `Map` inside the `mapToPair` function then my program runs out of memory. If I don't access the `Map`, then it executes successfully, even if I access the map in the main loop of the code. Any thoughts on why this might be happening? My hypothesis is that accessing the `Map` inside the anonymous function is causing Spark to duplicate it a lot of times.

I'm running Spark in Local mode with 16 threads. The issue occurs for anything from 16 to 4000 partitions of the data.

Code example:

**Working Code**:

```
JavaPairRDD<Integer, CustomObject> pairRDD = createRDD();
while(loop_condition = true) {
    Map<Integer, CustomObject> bigLocalMap = createMap();
    System.out.println(bigLocalMap.size());
    pairRDD = pairRDD.mapToPair(pair -> {
        return pair;
    }
}
```

**Not Working Code**

```
JavaPairRDD<Integer, CustomObject> pairRDD = createRDD();
while(loop_condition = true) {
    Map<Integer, CustomObject> bigLocalMap = createMap();
    pairRDD = pairRDD.mapToPair(pair -> {
        System.out.println(bigLocalMap.size());
        return pair;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How big is `bigLocalMap`?  The way you are referencing it (via a closure) requires it to be serialized and sent to every executor for every core.  Instead you should pass it around as a broadcast variable.

The general idea is you can register data that you want to be accessible on all of the executors and spark will ensure that the data is effeciently transferred and only stored once per executor.  With the closure method you will end up with duplicates if you have configured executors to have multiple cores.

Reference:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#broadcast-variables

If you are still running out of memory, I would take a look at your memory settings.  Some candidates for addressing it would be to:

- Reduce the number of cores per executor (less simultaneous tasks using memory)
- Increase the number of partitions, either by setting `spark.default.parallelism` and `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` (which will only take affect after the first shuffle) or by explicitly calling repartition.  Smaller tasks will have less memory pressure.
- If you have the resources, increase the amount of RAM you are giving to your executors with the `spark.executor.memory` setting

Comment: Thanks Ryan! I switched it to a broadcast variable and that seemed to resolve that OOM issue. Is there a general way to avoid spark duplicating local variable when running in local mode? I'm using some Spark default methods / classes that are now crashing due to the size of `bigLocalMap` but I can't get into their innards to make them broadcast the local variables instead of duplicating them across tasks.

Comment: I'm not sure without seeing the problematic code.  In general though, I would say if you are having memory issues still with the above recommendations, you might need to consider loading your `bigLocalMap` as a DataFrame or RDD instead and using the built in distributed operations to join it to your data as you see fit.  Performance wise, you are usually better off doing things with DataFrames.